# Multi-part form and wp_redirect()

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, forms, wp-redirect

For starters, it's a plugin (with a shortcode) or at least I would prefer it to be.

I've got two issues both related to wp_direct.

If form 1 validates I want to redirect to form 2, and continue the process.

If the visitor tries to start at form 2 without first having filled out form 1, then I want to redirect them back to form 1.

I've tried a number of different things and I continue to get "Cannot modify header". Even when the __construct() uses add_action ''send_headers' I still get the header error. How do I validate a form, redirect and then display a second form.

This hardly seems like an advance need. Yet I've spend a good part of the day looking for answers and here I am begging for help :)

Thanks in advance.

p.s. wp_safe_redirect() doesn't show up in the tags list.

Comment: You should really add some informations to your question. What code do you have? Where does the forms appear (sidebar, main page, within a post/page). When and where does the 'headers already send' error appear.

Answer (score 0):

You have a form like

```
<form action="http://some/url/form_two.php" method="POST">
 <input type="whatever" value="nothing" />
 <input type="hidden" name="form_one_displayed" value="1" />
 <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

in e.g `form_one.php`

In `form_two.php` you validate the data that was send (or not)

```
<?php
$result = do_some_validation_with( $_POST );

if ( false == $result )
  wp_redirect( 'form_one.php' );
else
  display_form_two();

function do_some_validation_with( $postdata = array() ) {
  // nothing was send
  if ( empty( $postdata ) )
    return false;

  // if the first form wasn't send, stop validation
  if ( ! isset( $postdata['form_one_displayed'] ) )
    return false;

  // do more validation

  // if validation pass
  return true;
}

function display_form_two() {}
```

I think it is easier to use an ajax request to validate the form data and display the second form only if the first one was validated.